# Installing MongoDB Drivers on Laravel Forge HHVM Server

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, hhvm

How do i solve this issue? I've been trying to install MongoDB HHVM Driver on Ubuntu 16.04 (Laravel Forge Server) following these instructions: [Manually Installing the MongoDB HHVM Driver][1]

I've gone through all the instructions until this part

```
make -j 5
```

When i run this command, i get the following error:

```
root@api:/hhvm-mongodb/hhvm-mongodb-1.1.2# make -j 4
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'CMakeFiles/mongodb.dir/build'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mongodb.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mongodb.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here are more details of my environment and drivers version:

MongoDB HHVM Driver 1.1.2

**Laravel Forge Server Details**

**HHVM Version**

```
HipHop VM 3.14.2 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.14.2-0-ge8134a09af2bc6e27191a63b6ed2f113ac80ee92
Repo schema: 676c6f18d2f55ba8ce519ca7af4c26a9747c1563
```

**PHP Version**

```
PHP 7.0.8-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by     Zend Technologies
```

**Laravel Version**

```
"laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
```

**MongoDB Version**

```
root@api:/# mongod --version
db version v2.6.10
2016-07-13T16:17:56.085+0200 git version: nogitversion
2016-07-13T16:17:56.085+0200 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016`
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB HHVM Driver Installation Documentation has been [updated](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hhvm-driver).

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hhvm-driver --branch master
cd mongo-hhvm-driver/
git submodule update --init --recursive
hphpize
cmake .
make configlib
make -j [number_of_processor_cores] # eg. make -j 4
make install
```